# How to reset a broken WooCommerce category page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

My client has managed to break the WooCommerce Category page and I cannot figure out how to fix it or what she's done.

Is there a way to reset a category product page in WooCommerce?

Shop is working but when I click on a category it shows a static image (same for all categories) and the search result in text form, eg "Showing 1–12 of 16 results Sort by popularity Sort by average rating Sort by latest Sort by price: low to high Sort by price: high to low Measuring CupsRated 0 out of 5 $24.95 Buy Now Sale!".
No image. No "Add to cart"-buttons, nothing else.

Comment: Can you enable the error log and check if any error pops-up? Also try changing the theme to a default 2022 theme and see if this solves the issue.

Comment: The theme she's using has lots and lots of customisations (widgets, CSS, settings) from years back, will this all come back as is if I switch theme and then switch back?

Comment: Any chance there's a recent backup of the site? If so then you may be able to restore the site to the state it had prior to client's changes.

Comment: @Sara Yes. It will come back if you switch back theme after testing. Just take a backup before doing so